# 3-vote close - how's it going?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Part of understanding the impact of three-vote closure is to understand what impact it's having on y'all. I'd like to ask anyone who feels up to it to **write an answer to this question** and to tell us about your experience over the past few weeks.

The sorts of things I'm interested in knowing (feel free to address all or none or add your own) -

- Did this help?
- Did it hurt?
- Did it make you more interested in close/reopen reviewing? Less?

  - Are there things other than 3-vote close impacting your interest in reviewing?
- If you can't vote but do flag, did this make you more/less likely to flag?
- Would you prefer to go back to 5?
- Should it be permanent?
- What would you like me to look into when it comes to analyzing the data from the test?
- Were there any side-effects (good or bad) that you want me to be aware of?

These are merely prompts, so feel free to add anything I'm missing that you think is worth saying. This is focused on how you're feeling about it and what data you want me to look at, so don't feel like you need to analyze the data over the last 30 days - though you're welcome to if that's how you figure out what you feel.

If you have any outstanding questions, also feel welcome to ask them here.

The test will run until about Monday the 21st of June, at which point we'll be resetting the votes to close up to 5 while I review the responses here and dig into the data that we've been collecting.

Answer (score 3):

My two cents: I like it.

As a community we don't have a large number of people who use their close votes regularly, which inevitably leads to more votes/closures by moderators. I think it's fair to say that this used to happen more than most people would have liked.

Having the limit reduced means we (mods) have been able to much more comfortably take a step back and let things take their natural course via the community. I think this is much more satisfying for everyone, and helps to keep that oppressive kind of feeling that can happen on these sites from creeping in.

I've thought long and hard and can't think of anything I don't like about it, my vote would be to keep it!